# How to union 2 columns in R

Tags: r, union-all

I have two tables and I need to union 2 columns in 1. Each column from a different table.
I'd like to create a new table with column z where I will have every value from x & y with dublicates.
Can you guys help me with that?

```
id x 
1  p
2  e
3  p 


id y
1  e
2 
3  e
```

Comment: Can you please include the expected output (in data form) given these two tables?

Comment: Please post what you want the final output to look like.

Comment: I'd like to have one table z with all the vaules -> p,e,p,e,e etc. I need to count how many is vaule 'e' vs 'p'

Comment: If you want to count occurrences, how about `table(c(df1$x, df2$y))`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for such a solution: here is an example step by step:

```
table1 <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3),
                 x= c("p", "e", "p"))
table1

table2 <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3),
                 x= c("e", NA, "e"))
table2

table3 <- bind_rows(table1, table2)
table3$z <- table3$x
table3 <- table3[,3]
table3
```

Output:

```
  z    
  <chr>
1 p    
2 e    
3 p    
4 e    
5 NA   
6 e
```

Comment: Doesn't really work ;/ I have already some data in those 2 column are the same but columns' names are different

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(table1, table2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
> list2DF(Map(c, df1, df2))
  id    x
1  1    p
2  2    e
3  3    p
4  1    e
5  2 <NA>
6  3    e
```